# Is “senior year” a direct object or something else in “I played my senior year”? What about “perfect game” in “I threw a perfect game”?

Tags: meaning, adverbials, direct-objects

In the sentence “I played my senior year” (Referring to baseball) would senior year be an adverbial phrase or a direct object?

Would the same apply to “I threw a perfect game”? In the second example it is confusing because it doesn’t seem like “perfect game” is receiving action rather it would make more sense for something like a ball to be thrown based on the definition of throw. Would this also make it an adverbial phrase?

Answer (score 5):

In "throw a game" the thing you are throwing is a game, so it's a direct object. (The use of "throw" in this sense is figurative; it doesn't really matter that the game isn't literally being thrown.)

In "I played [baseball] [in] my senior year" the noun phrase with the year is an adverbial which governs the duration of the verb phrase "I played". What you played is implied, "[baseball]". The adverbial answers the question "when".

Comment: _Throw a game_ is ambiguous. In baseball, it means to be the pitcher during a game. It can also mean to lose the game on purpose for money.

Comment: But the OP's example is actually "throw a perfect game."

Comment: Then the "perfect" part makes it unambiguously "be a pitcher during a game". A baseball "perfect game" means a game in which one or more pitchers complete a minimum of nine innings with no batter from the opposing team reaching any base. In practice, it's only one pitcher that does this, and it's very very rare.

Comment: "Threw a perfect game" is still ambiguous - it _could_ mean that the game was ideal, but was "thrown" (i. e. deliberately lost). "Tim: Why are you down Joe? Joe: I threw a perfect game! Everything was in the bag, but I owed Charlie the Rat and so I deliberately miffed that catch!"

I will grant you that that usage is not the common case.